# Laravel 5.2 - Validation errors are not getting displayed

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to validate a login/signup system in Laravel 5.2.

I'm using `welcome.blade.php` as the index page which contains two forms for both signup and signin

This is how my `UserController.php` is set up:

```
namespace authme\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use authme\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getDashboard()
    {
        return view('dashboard');
    }
    public function doSignUp(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'first_name' => 'required|max:120',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        $email = $request['email'];
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']);
        $first_name = $request['first_name'];
        $last_name = $request['last_name'];
        $location = $request['location'];
        $phone = $request['phone'];

        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->password = $password;
        $user->firstname = $first_name;
        $user->lastname = $last_name;
        $user->location = $location;
        $user->phone = $phone;

        $user->save();

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');

    }

    public function doSignIn(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])){
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

To show the errors during signup/login, in my view file (`welcome.blade.php`), I've included:

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="row">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

and the routes are set up like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/signup', [
    'uses'  => 'UserController@doSignUp',
    'as' => 'signup'
]);

Route::post('/signin', [
    'uses'  => 'UserController@doSignIn',
    'as' => 'signin'
]);

Route::get('/dashboard', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
    'as' => 'dashboard'
]);
});
```

The forms are working fine when entering correct details. However when I enter incorrect data:

- When I try to submit the blank form, it just redirects back to the original page, but no errors are shown
- When I try to enter an email that is already in use, it again redirects back to the original page, but no errors are displayed

However, I couldn't find any possible syntax error in my code. Is there any logical errors?

PS:

1. I've not edited or modified `App\Exceptions\Handler`
2. None of the answers to questions asked both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888232/laravel-5-2-validation-errors-not-appearing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509394/laravel-5-validation-errors-are-not-showing) solves my problem

Comment: Take a look at [Validation error in Laravel - $errors array does not get populated after the validation failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503825/validation-error-in-laravel-errors-array-does-not-get-populated-after-the-val)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Laravel version higher or equal to 5.2.25 you no longer need to put your routes in the `web` middleware. It is now automatically applied.

Putting your routes in the `web` middleware in the `routes.php` actually causes the problem.

Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503825/validation-error-in-laravel-errors-array-does-not-get-populated-after-the-val).

Comment: Removing routes from `web` middleware worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use following codes to show the errors for sign in with invalid credential.

```
public function doSignIn(Request $request)
{
    $rules = array(
        'email'    => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()){
            return redirect('welcome')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }else{
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])){
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your validation error messages are not getting saved to the session. Have a look at this.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12022