# Input Validation in Laravel won't show errors

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I am new to Laravel and was trying to validate inputs to a form. I use blade templating engine. The validation works because, it doesn't insert data into the db but the errors don't show up either. Here is what I did for my SignUp form:

```
@section('content')
    @if(count($errors)>0)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{$error}}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Sign Up</h3>
            <form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username :</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name :</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">E-Mail :</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password :</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            </form>
        </div>
@endsection
```

Also here is my login where I validate the fields and make the user logged in:

```
public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required|unique:users|max:20|min:2',
            'name' => 'required|max:30|min:2',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users|max:50|min:5',
            'password' => 'required|min:4'
        ]);

        $username = $request["username"];
        $name = $request["name"];
        $email = $request["email"];
        $password = bcrypt($request["password"]);

        $user = new User();
        $user->username = $username;
        $user->name = $name;
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->password = $password;
        $user->save();
        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
```

**For some reason, when I do a already taken username or wrong email and click on Submit button, it redirects me back to the signup page which is the expected functionality but it doesn't show the errors at all.**

EDIT: Here is my route.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function (){
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::post('/signup', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
        'as' => 'signup'
    ]);

    Route::post('/signin', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@postSignIn',
            'as' => 'signin'
    ]);

    Route::get('/dashboard', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
        'as' => 'dashboard'
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Please post the code of your `route.php` file.

Comment: change {{ }} to {!!  !!}

Comment: Which {{ }} should I change to {!! !!}? The one containing the $error? I tried, it didn't work. Also I have updated my route.php in the question as requested

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation error in Laravel - $errors array does not get populated after the validation failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503825/validation-error-in-laravel-errors-array-does-not-get-populated-after-the-val)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this in your blade:

```
@section('content')
    @if($errors->any())
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{$error}}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Sign Up</h3>
            <form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username :</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name :</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">E-Mail :</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password :</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            </form>
        </div>
@endsection
```